# Move folders containing files with extension

Tags: shell, script

Example folder structure:

```
➜  test tree
.
├── testflac1
│   ├── track1.flac
│   ├── track2.flac
│   └── track3.flac
├── testflac2
│   ├── track1.flac
│   ├── track2.flac
│   └── track3.flac
├── testflac3
│   ├── track1.flac
│   ├── track2.flac
│   └── track3.flac
├── testmp31
│   ├── track1.mp3
│   ├── track2.mp3
│   └── track3.mp3
├── testmp32
│   ├── track1.mp3
│   ├── track2.mp3
│   └── track3.mp3
└── testmp33
    ├── track1.mp3
    ├── track2.mp3
    └── track3.mp3
```

And the goal would be to move folders that contain one extension to one directory, like `~/test [FLAC]` and others containing `mp3` extension to `~/test [MP3]`. I tried out doing that with `find`, but that only allowed me to do move files themselves, without retaining folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
shopt -s nullglob; for dir in path/to/*/; do files=("$dir"/*{mp3,flac}); [ "${files[0]}" ] && mv "$dir" ~/test; done
```

Or, for those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in path/to/*/
do
    files=("$dir"/*{mp3,flac})
    [ "${files[0]}" ] && mv "$dir" ~/test
done
```

Before running that, of course, change `path/to/` to whatever gets you to your test dir as shown in the question.  Then, `path/to/*/` should expand to all the directories of interest.

#### How it works

- `shopt -s nullglob`

  This sets nullglob so that a pathname expansion that returns no files will return an empty string.
- `for dir in path/to/*/; do`

  This starts a loop over all directories in your test dir.
- `files=("$dir"/*{mp3,flac})`

  This creates an array whose elements are any file names in `$dir` that end in `mp3` or `flac`.
- `[ "${files[0]}" ] && mv "$dir" ~/test`

  If the array `files` is not empty (meaning that there is at least one mp3 or flac file in the directory), then move directory `dir` to `~/test`.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.