# move folders that contain a string and keep folder structure

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a *F:\Music* folder with a lot of subfolders, some of them contain the [flac] **string** in their folder name, I like to **move all the folders with their contents**, that contain the [flac] string, into a **new folder** while **keeping all the folder structures**. Some paths go deeper than just one folder.

```
get-item "F:\Music\*\*[flac]" | 
foreach ($_){
    $oldpath = $_.FullName; 
    $newpath = "F:\Musicflac\"+$_.Parent; 
    robocopy $oldpath $newpath /MOVE /E
}
```

After searching and trying I came to this PS script, returning no errors but also no results. I found a similar topic but this only works in bash: [Move folders containing files with extension](https://superuser.com/questions/1409085/move-folders-containing-files-with-extension).
*I'm completely new to PowerShell.*

### Edit 1:

I also tried with Move-Item:

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem "F:\Music\*\*[flac]" | select fullname | ForEach-Object {$_.fullname}
$destination = "F:\Musicflac\"
foreach ($path in $paths){
    Move-Item $path -Destination $destination
}
```

Also nothing happens, the difficulties for me are: 
the **must contain string** *[flac]* and the **keep folder structure**.

### Edit 2:

Your script gave some errors in the first place but after some adjustements I finally got results:

```
gci "F:\Zandbak\Music\" -directory -recurse -filter '*[flac]*' |
   %{
        #calculate new path
        $newpath = $_.fullname -replace 'Music', 'Musicflac'

        #check if new path excists, if not create it
        if(!(test-path -Path $newpath)){ new-item $newpath -itemType directory }

        #move the directory and its contents to another directory
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $newpath
   }
```

**No more errors** and the **correct folders** in the Musicflac directory are **being created**! Unfortunately the **files in the folders** are not moved along with the folders, **only empty directories are being created**.

Any advice for **also moving the folder contents**?

### Edit 3:

directory structure:

```
F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen\2011 A winged victory for the sullen
F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen\2011 A winged victory for the sullen [flac]
F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen\2011 A winged victory for the sullen\2014 Atomos IXII
F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen\2011 A winged victory for the sullen\2014 Atomos IXII [FLAC]
F:\Zandbak\Musicflac
```

Comment: For moving, no need to use robocopy when [Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6) does the job:  `Move-Item -Path $oldpath -Destination $newpath`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried that, but also no result, I described my difficulties in the Edit above.

Comment: Try `Move-Item -Path "$oldpath" -Destination "$newpath"`

Comment: @harrymc I made the change but same result, no errors. I think it is more of a logical error in the loop structure or wildcard?

Comment: Does this work? `Get-ChildItem F:\Music -Filter "*[flac]*" -Recurse | ? { $_.PsIsContainer } | foreach { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "F:\Musicflac" }`

Comment: Nothing :( --also added the `-Verbose` to get some feedback but no answer from PS. Than I addad the band name because maybe the loop is not looking in subfolders... This is the structure: _"\Music\Band\Album [flac]"_
`Get-ChildItem "F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen\" -Filter "*[flac]*" -Recurse | ? { $_.PsIsContainer } | foreach { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "F:\Zandbak\Musicflac" } -Verbose`

Answer (score 0):

My reputation isn't good enough to comment yet :D

Have you verified you're getting the items to begin with? Testing your Get-ChildItem command alone to see if it returns the desired folders?

I suggest trying:

```
gci "F:\Zandbak\Music" -directory -recurse -filter '*[flac]*' |
   %{
     $newpath = $_.Parent.fullname -replace 'F:\\Zandbak\\Music', 'F:\Zandbak\Musicflac'
     If (!(test-path $newpath))
        {new-item $newpath -itemType directory -whatif}
     Move-Item $_.FullName $newpath -Whatif
   }
```

If the output from the above code indicates it will create & move thee correct folders, remove the '-WhatIf' pareameters from new-item and move-item.

Keith

Comment: I did some further testing and I partially made it work thanks to your code. Now only the folders are moved and not the contents within. I made an edit to your post with the working code (Edit 2)

Comment: What errors were you getting with my code? Other than the fact that your original post didn't specify that Music was a sub-directory of Zandbak?

Comment: I think I see where your edits went wrong. In the $newpath assignment statement, you replaced '$_.Parent.FullName' with '$_.fullname' and proceeded to use it as an arguement for 'new-item', thus creating an empty folder with the same name of the folder you want to move ---- thereby blocking 'move-item' from moving the source folder, as a folder with the same name now already exists.  My reference to the parent folder and subsequent creation of the structure only up to the parent was intentional & necessary for 'move-item' to function correctly.

Comment: So, at this point, you need to delete the new empty folder structure before running the code again. Also, I intentionally searched & replaced for the root of the path rather than simply the word 'music' because the word 'music' is quite common in many album names. Not knowing the names of all your sub folders, I didn't want to change "The Music of blan-blah-blah" to "The Muiscflac of blah-blah-blah".. The double slashes are necessary in the search parameter of the '-replace' operator (but not the replace parameter) because it is a regular expression, so backslashes must be escaped.

Comment: I edited the path names in my code to reflect the paths shown in your latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I am not getting any errors with your code, but also nothing happens (or got moved) when I execute it (neither without the -whatif). That's why I started changing your code until it I saw something happening. Like you said it creates the new folders but also blocks the move later as the paths already exist. I don't know why your code is not working. Maybe I give you my directory structure so you can make a better simulation (Edit 3)?

Comment: Oh and another question about the regular expression, why needs the first parameter need to by escaped from \ and the second not? Is it because the syntax is -replace (regex, string) ?

Comment: Yes, the '\' is the escape character in a regex, so if you want to search for a literal '\', you use '\\'. If my code isn't doing anything and also isn't generating any errors, the most likely cause is that get-childitem isn't returning anything, so let's check that in isolation. Does 'gci "F:\Zandbak\Music" -directory -recurse -filter '*[flac]*' | select fullname' (without the single quotes surrounding the entire statement) return the list of folders you want to move?

Comment: Like you suspected, it returns nothing. But if I output the $newpath var in the foreach loop: it outputs 'F:\Zandbak\Musicflac\A Winged Victory for the Sullen' **2 times**. As there are **2 folders** containing the string [flac] the loop is executed correctly, only is the gci function not returning paths.

Comment: Now I'm confused. If the test of Get-ChildItem didn't return anything, there would be no input for the foreach. Also, your example path,  'F:\Zandbak\Music\A Winged Victory for the Sullen' , doesn't contain '[flac]', so it shouldn't have been found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92577/discussion-between-kleajmp-and-keith-miller).